# JSON returning empty array for select query from PHP without any Error

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic2

I have passed values using post from Angular component to PHP and able to view the passed input values but when using inputs in select query unable to fetch any records
PHP Code:

```
    $json    =  file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj     =  json_decode($json);


    $selectedDept = filter_var($obj->selectyear, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
    $selectedYear = filter_var($obj->selectDepart, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

   $searchdata = array();

    try {
      $stmt     = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM circular_data WHERE YEAR(Circular_date)=:selectyear AND Circular_department=:selectDepart');
            $stmt->bindParam(':selectyear', $selectedYear);
            $stmt->bindParam(':selectDepart', $selectedDept);
            $stmt->execute();

      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         // Assign each row of data to associative array
         $searchdata[] = $row;
      }

      echo json_encode($searchdata);
   }

   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Component Class code where inputs passed using POST request:

```
this.selectedData = {
    selectyear: this.selectedYear,
    selectDepart: this.selectedDepartment
  }

  let selectData = this.selectedData;

  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/dbcon/retrieve-searchdata.php', selectData, httpOptions)
  .subscribe((searchdata : any) =>
  {
      console.log(searchdata);
  },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured", err);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Just in case (been there, done that): that query should produce results? As in, there is data in the database?

Comment: Try hitting this API with a POST Request in postman if the API is indeed working.

Comment: is data available in database or api posting some data ? postman it

Comment: API is working fine in POSTMAN, some issue while returning JSON data after select query, if i print some message echo json_encode("Your record is fetched"); instead of echo json_encode($searchdata), able to view the output